# How do I BringIntoView in Win8

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, scrollviewer

given an index of an item inside an `ItemsControl`, I'm trying to bring it into view by using `BringIntoView` ->

```
var container = theItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as Control;
if (container != null)
  container.BringIntoView();
```

This works in WPF, but not in Win8 - is the method missing? is there any other way to achieve this effect?

Comment: Have you seen http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/77626f2e-37db-4fbb-aa18-1133812d7c2b/where-is-bringintoview?forum=winappswithcsharp or possibly http://conan0101.blogspot.com/2013/05/windows-8-how-to-set-item-to-bring-into.html ?

Comment: Please stop creating a new tag for Windows 8.  We already have a tag for it, and it's not relevant here.  Maybe you're talking about Windows Runtime?  Or perhaps Windows Store Apps?  That's an entirely different thing.

Comment: The [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23464078) provides a BringIntoView implementation.